# Equation alignment without equation index?

Tags: equations, align

I asked about this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10938247#10938247) but dead silent. So how can I align an equation without getting the equation index number?

Comment: Use `align*` instead of `align`.

Comment: @karlkoeller worked like a charm! Solved. Is this worth a thread?

Comment: IMHO, everything regarding TeX is worth here. Even when it is a duplicate (one might not find it him/herself)!